# DAC was modified by another process

Tags: erp, acumatica

I've created APTax dac class, added view for it in graph:

```
public PXSelect<APTax> taxes;
```

then in my graph I have the following:

```
var currentTax = taxes.Cache.Current;
currentTax.Percent = 3.25;
//some other assignments
taxes.Cache.Update(currentTax);
taxes.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
```

but I receive error message APTax was modified by another process. What I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you to check how you located in your class attribute IsKey. Most often I got this error message in cases when in db I had one configuration of keys fields, but in DAC class another. They not necessary should be the same, but IsKey should be located in your DAC class uniquely.